# Is it possible to make a video background in Tkinker?

Tags: python, tkinter, video, background

I'm very new to Tkinker and I'm trying to learn about it, but my plan would be to make a window with a video as a background and labels and buttons on top.

I've been looking about it for hours but I honestly don't know if it is possible or not...
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tkVideo`](https://pypi.org/project/tkVideo/) to show a video in `tkinter`.

You need to create a `label` to be the parent of a `tkvideo` object.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkvideo import tkvideo

root = tk.Tk()
lbl = tk.Label(root)
player = tkvideo("Your\\path\\here", lbl, loop=1) # loops infinitely
player.play()
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want the video to be played at the background you can create a parent frame and then add things to the frame:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkvideo import tkvideo

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
lbl = tk.Label(frame)
player = tkvideo("Your Path here", lbl, loop=1)
player.play()
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Click Me")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```